# Attempting to change an image onclick via PHP/Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've looked at numerous other answers regarding this but haven't found a solution that has worked. I'm using a PHP page that contains some HTML code, with Javascript working some functions. Ideally I would select an image on the page, the image will become colored green as it is selected. I would then like to deselect the image and have it return to the original state. I can only get half-way there however. What am I missing? Is it something with post back?

Here's some code examples:
The HTML:
`<div onclick="changeImage(1)" id="toolDiv1"><img id="imgCh1" src="/images/Tooling/1.png"></div>`

The Javascript function:

```
        function changeImage(var i){
            var img = document.getElementById("imgCh" + i + ".png");

            if (img.src === "images/Tooling/" + i + ".png"){
                img.src = "images/Tooling/" + i + "c.png";
            }
            else
            {
                img.src = "images/Tooling/" + i + ".png";
            }
        }`
```

The "1c.png" image is the one that is selected and should replace "1.png". There are multiple divs on this page that hold multiple images, which are named 2/2c, 3/3c, which is why the var i is included. Any insight? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `".png"` isn't part of the element's `id`. Don't add it; just look for `"imgCh" + i`.

Comment: What do you mean you've only got it half way? Your element ID doesn't match (you included `.png`) and your image sources are different (starts with `/` then is changed to a relative location) so it will take multiple clicks to initiate. Additionally, rather than loading a whole separate image you could consider adding a green filter over the top of the image to lower network usage.

Comment: Can i make change in jQuery ?

Comment: @D.R. I didn't realize that I copied code from an earlier revision that included that - it normally isn't in the id and has been since removed. Sorry about that. I'll look into filters as an option, I didn't think of that. I appreciate the insight, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it something like this, it would also allow for different file names.

```
<img class="selectable" src="/images/Tooling/1.png"
                        data-original-source="/images/Tooling/1.png"
                        data-selected-source="/images/Tooling/1c.png">

<img class="selectable" src="/images/Tooling/2.png"
                        data-original-source="/images/Tooling/2.png"
                        data-selected-source="/images/Tooling/2c.png">
```

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('selectable');

for (var image of images) {
  image.addEventListener('click', selectElementHandler);
}

function selectElementHandler(event) {
  var image = event.target,
      currentSrc  = image.getAttribute('src'),
      originalSrc = image.getAttribute('data-original-source'),
      selectedSrc = image.getAttribute('data-selected-source'),
      newSrc = currentSrc === originalSrc ? selectedSrc : originalSrc;

  image.setAttribute('src', newSrc);
}
```

With comments:

```
// find all images with class "selectable"
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('selectable');

// add an event listener to each image that on click runs the "selectElementHandler" function
for (var image of images) {
  image.addEventListener('click', selectElementHandler);
}

// the handler receives the event from the listener
function selectElementHandler(event) {
  // the event contains lots of data, but we're only interested in which element was clicked (event.target)
  var image = event.target,
      currentSrc  = image.getAttribute('src'),
      originalSrc = image.getAttribute('data-original-source'),
      selectedSrc = image.getAttribute('data-selected-source'),
      // if the current src is the original one, set to selected
      // if not we assume the current src is the selected one
      // and we reset it to the original src
      newSrc = currentSrc === originalSrc ? selectedSrc : originalSrc;

  // actually set the new src for the image
  image.setAttribute('src', newSrc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this was exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the breakdown as well!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that javascript is returning the full path of the `src` (you can try `alert(img.src);` to verify this).

You could look up how to parse a file path to get the file name in javascript, if you want the most robust solution.

However, if you're sure that all your images will end in 'c.png', you could check for those last 5 characters, using a substring of the last 5 characters:

```
function changeImage(var i){
    var img = document.getElementById("imgCh" + i);

    if (img.src.substring(img.src.length - 5) === "c.png"){
        img.src = "images/Tooling/" + i + ".png";
    }
    else
    {
        img.src = "images/Tooling/" + i + "c.png";
    }
}
```